# Bootstrap/Rails - String Interpolation inside accordion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I've been struggling with string interpolation inside an HTML accordion. It's more a logic issue that I can't seem to figure out (fairly new to rails). The problem I have is that while the layout is fine, when I click to collapse any of the 3 collapsible panels they all collapse. (Because I only have 1 #collapse).

Outermost ERB

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                <h2>Categorias</h2>
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <%= render partial: "categories/catalog", collection: @categories, as: :c %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

_catalog Partial

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                <%= c.name %>
                <span class="badge">4</span>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <% c.subcategories.each do |sc| %>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#">
                    <%= sc.name %>
                </a>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
  def catalogo
    @categories = Category.where("parent_id IS NULL")
    unless params[:cat_id].blank?
      @products = Product.where(category_id: params[:cat_id]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
    else
      @products = Product.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
    end
      @categorieswparent = Category.where("parent_id IS NOT NULL")
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDs need to be unique. Instead of hard-coding `id="collapse1"`, use the ID of the record:

```
id="collapse<%= sc.id %>"
```

Perform the same interpolation for the `href` of the `<a>` tag responsible for collapsing and expanding the accordion.

Comment: Thanks meagar, I added the same interpolation to the href and the ID but that messed up my panels. Could you be little more concise (I'm very confused) Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Use category id `id="#collapse<%= c.id %>"` to interpolate with element id in `_catalog` Partial.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%= c.id %>">
                <%= c.name %>
                <span class="badge">4</span>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<%= c.id %>" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <% c.subcategories.each do |sc| %>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="#">
                    <%= sc.name %>
                </a>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak, that makes sense but I tried it and now the panels won't collapse

Comment: @Dotol You have to change at both places line:4 and line:10